# How to run Genymotion with android view client?

Tags: android, android-emulator, androidviewclient

I am running my app in genymotion emulator, am trying to access the app from android view client python library, but can't seem to find a way to access it. View client only takes port for access, so i can't work with IP address of the remote virtual machine. It would be helpful if you guys can help out and tell me how do i access genymotion emulator via ip address and port.

Comment: **AndroidViewClient** connects to the device or emulator via `adb` then you must have it listed in `adb devices`, otherwise you have to establish the `adb` connection first.

Comment: The `adb` connection can be via TCP: `List of devices attached
192.168.2.200:5555 device`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who comes here after me. I found the signature for connectToDeviceOrExit() in [viewclient.py](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py) from GitHub to be this:

> connectToDeviceOrExit(timeout=60, verbose=False, ignoresecuredevice=False, ignoreversioncheck=False, serialno=None)

You can therefore do the following to use Android View Client with Genymotion:

> from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
>
> vc = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(serialno="192.168.2.200:5555"))